# Rotating a line across x/y axis and finding the surface area.

Tags: calculus, integration

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol7aG.png)

Can someone explain how I do this? I did the other line easily. It seems to form a conical frustum, but when I try and use the formula for that surface area, I lack the radius for the top and bottom circle. I see they give me the radius from the center, how do I utilize that instead?

Comment: Use [Pappus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#The_first_theorem).

Comment: Do you know the slope of the red line?

Comment: No I do not know the slope, that is all the information given to me. Thanks Bobbie, seems that is the theorem I need.